# .on('click') works and doesn't works (IE and Edge)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

So i have an issue with the .on('click') on IE and Edge

This my code where the issue is :

```
$('.titleMarge').on('click',function(){
        $('.margeConfig').css('display','block');
        $('.borderDivConfig').css('display','none');
        $('.shadowConfig').css('display','none');

        $('.activeMarge').html('&#x25c4');
        $('.activeBorder').html('');
        $('.activeOmbre').html('');
    });

    $('.titleBorder').on('click',function(){
        $('.borderDivConfig').css('display','block');
        $('.margeConfig').css('display','none');
        $('.shadowConfig').css('display','none');

        $('.activeMarge').html('');
        $('.activeBorder').html('&#x25c4');
        $('.activeOmbre').html('');
    });

    $('.titleShadow').on('click',function(){
        $('.shadowConfig').css('display','block');
        $('.borderDivConfig').css('display','none');
        $('.margeConfig').css('display','none');

        $('.activeMarge').html('');
        $('.activeBorder').html('');
        $('.activeOmbre').html('&#x25c4');
    });
```

On all other browsers, this works fine but on IE and Edge only the $('.titleBorder') doesn't work..

Any idea ?

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: only `$('.titleBorder')` click event is not working ?

Comment: Can you open developer tool in IE and check console.

Comment: Well, i forgot to mention that there is 0 error in the console
That's the trick...

And yes only $('.titleBorder') click event is not working

Comment: Can you also add a snippet of html to check for errors?

Comment: Oh my...
I'm so stupid, I didn't know that IE and Edge are case sensitive. 
I, accidentally, wrote <h3 class="TitleBorder"> with a 'T' instead of a 't' 
When testing my code on Chrome, Firefox , ... No errors and everything works fine
So my guess is that IE and Edge are case sensitive

Thanks everyone !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my... I'm so stupid, I didn't know that IE and Edge are case sensitive.
 I, accidentally, wrote `<h3 class="TitleBorder">` with a 'T' instead of a 't' When testing my code on Chrome, Firefox , ... No errors and everything works fine So my guess is that IE and Edge are case sensitive Thanks everyone !